# break long word around floating image

Tags: css, css-float, word-wrap

I am trying to create a page display on mobile. Its layout like this:

```
/---------\ some text around 
|         | the image. some
|  image  | text around the
|         | image. some text
\---------/ around the image.
some word around the image.
some word around the image.
```

I use floating style to implement that:

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;">
  <img src="someimg.jpg" style="float: left;"/>
  some text around the image. some text around the image. ...
</div>
```

However, if the word is longer than the right area max length but shorter than the whole div, it won't be break, instead it just be moved below the image.

```
/---------\ some text around 
|         | the image.
|  image  | 
|         | 
\---------/ 
a-word-longer-than-right will
not be break and just display
below the image while a-word-
longer-than-the-whole-area-wi
ll-be-break-into-next-line
```

How can I break the word longer than right side and fill the empty area up?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the issue you are describing. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QYVmK/ As you can see, the long text wraps just like you want. I tested with Firefox 5.0. Could you post an example in jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the issue? Which browser are you using to test?

Comment: I could reproduce it here in FF 5: http://jsfiddle.net/BMYqx/

Comment: Floern's jsfiddle also breaks in chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert `&shy;` soft-breaks in the long word. There are various PHP libraries that can do that for you, based on dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks, now I use soft hyphen (&shy;) to break words and zero-width space (&#8203;) to break numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Could use PHP to prep the text block, shortening long words with something like ...

```
    $words = explode(' ',$str);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strlen($word) > 20) {
            $part1 = substr($word,0,20);
            $part2 = substr($word,21);
            $newwords[] = $part1 .' '. $part2;
        } else {
            $newwords[] = $word;
        }
    }
    $newstr = implode(' ',$newwords);
```

Comment: 20 is not good. this page works on mobile. maybe the right side can only contain less than 10 letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can sprinkle `<wbr>` tags in the long word. The browser will use them to break whenever it is needs to. If not needed, it won't break there. Here is your jsfiddle example fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/vAdPy/

Note that the closer are the `<wbr>` tags to each other, the better results you get as the browser has more options to find a suitable place to break the long word.

Here is a PHP script to sprinkle `<wbr>` tags into the text.

```
<?php
    $word = 'thisisaverylongword';
    $wbr_word = preg_replace('/(..)/', '\\1<wbr>', $word);

    // $wbr_word is now "th<wbr>is<wbr>is<wbr>av<wbr>er<wbr>yl<wbr>on<wbr>gw<wbr>or<wbr>d"
?>
```

This inserts a `<wbr>` tag after every two characters (note the two dots in the regex) of the long-text. You can alter the number of dots in the regex to control how far apart two consecutive `<wbr>` tags should be.

Comment: <wbr> is not supported in Opera yet

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution was the best (with long words and float elements):

```
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-word;
     -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
```

http://blog.kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/

There are only problems in Chrome.